# C programming function

Tags: c

How would I write a function that takes an array of integer x and size y, and shuffles the elements of x at random by looping y^2 times. In each loop it would choose two random integers a and b in the interval [0, y-1] and swaps the elements stored at positions a and b of x?

What I've thought so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define array x

void permutation(int size) {
    int array[x];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) x[i] = i + 1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int swap_index = rand() % size;
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[swap_index];
        array[swap_index] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `#define` line and `i < x` are both nonsense.   The compiler should have warned you about the latter so make sure your warnings are on and you are reading them. 
 You need to either print the array or return it or your function is useless.  Returning the array requires you to change how you allocate it because it's a local variable right now.   Swapping only needs to happen `size` times if you do it right, where the first swap permanently decides which element will be in position 0, and the next swap permanently decides position 1, etc.  Also, only seed `srand` once (in `main`).

Comment: If you apply the line `#define array x` to the line `int array[x];`, then you will have `int x[x];`, which does not make sense.

Comment: Side note: If you are looking for a better shuffling algorithm, then you may want to look at [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). However, I don't want to discourage you from attempting to first use your own shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Can you use the title to explain your *technical* problem?

Comment: See [ask] on how to select an appropriate title for your question.

Comment: Please do not post homework problems to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

here is solution code for your problem!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void function(int arr[],unsigned int size) {
    int count=0;
    srand(time(0));
    while(count<(size*size)) {
        count++;
        int a=(rand()%size);
        int b=(rand()%size);
        int temp=arr[a];
        arr[a]=arr[b];
        arr[b]=temp;
    }
}

int main() {
   int array[]={3,4,6,7,8,0,1};
   function(array,7);
   for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
       printf("%d",array[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!...    I confess that was a big fault....I have changed as requirement...